# Atualizar pagina com a rota sem "#" AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Eu alterei as rotas para carregar as paginas sem o "#".

O problema é quando faço F5 ele retorna erro 404.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/Cadastros', { templateUrl: $("#linkBase").attr("href") + 'templates/Cadastro/cadastros.html', controller: 'CadastroController' })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

});
```

Comment: Qual é o seu servidor http?

Answer (score 1):

O erro 404 é enviado por causa da resposta do seu servidor http, que não reconhece a rota, já que o diretório não existe fisicamente, e nem a repassa para o controle do angular. É necessário que você configure seu servidor para que todo o tráfego que gere erro 404 seja reencaminhado para sua página inicial do angular. Deste modo, o angular tomará controle da requisição e poderá processar pela definições de rotas da aplicação.

Exemplo em nginx, com página inicial do angular em `/index.html`:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa determinar o mapeamento, no seu servidor, para a página-base.

Quando o usuário acessa a seguinte URL:

```
https://www.meuservidor.com/app/#cadastros/123
```

Na verdade, o conteúdo acessado é:

```
https://www.meuservidor.com/app/
               |                #cadastros/123
               |                      |
           Página-base           estado/rota
```

O que se traduz no servidor retornando, por exemplo, `~/app/index.html` - e deixando o tratamento de rota para o Angular.

Entretanto, se você acessar:

```
https://www.meuservidor.com/app/cadastros/123
```

Você irá provavelmente receber um 404. Isso acontece porque a URL contendo os parâmetros de rota é um endereço válido.

Você precisa então interceptar, no servidor, a URL fornecida pelo usuário e redirecionar para a sua página-base [como neste exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25731349/1845714).